# Can I add details after paypal payment with Rest API?

Tags: paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I would like to know if I can add some info to transaction AFTER the payment.

My web-app issues tickets but it knows the ticket-id-number only after the payment completion and I want to fill the transaction info with this details in case of contentious to prove that a ticket identified by its number was issued for that transaction.

Can I change or add item details after the payment?

Comment: when you say after payment - do you mean after /execute call ? or after create payment call ?

Comment: I mean after "execute" call.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to update the payment after the /execute call at least when you use intent as "sale"

A possible option would be to use intent as "authorize". when you do that /execute will return you an authorization id. since the payment is authorized you should be able to safely generate a ticket #

then when you are expected to do https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#authorization_capture

POST /v1/payments/authorization/{authorization_id}/capture

within this there is an option to pass an invoice_number - you could potentially use it to pass the ticket# ? such that your payment capture always has a reference to the ticket #

Now there is a chance that capture might fail but it should really be negligible as PYPL wouldn't authorize if it doesn't think it can capture especially in your case when you would initiate a capture moments later.

Comment: Unfortunately I already try to separate the authorization from execution, but I had to change the procedure because a transaction can hold in a situation where a ticket was issued and the payment execution fails and this is not acceptable because in italian law the cancellation of a ticket is a bit complicated (emitter should preserve the original ticket for many years...). I have to find a way to prove that a specific ticket was issued for the specific transaction but I cannot switch the issue and the payment execution.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no real solution to update transaction details  post payment processing - it seems unlikely that such would be ever supported as PayPal wouldn't want anyone updating payment transaction info post processing as well